# Magento, category, details button

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to teach myself Magento, and basic programming.
In the product lists I have, beside the "add to cart" button is a "Details" button. It has a typo in the label, and says "Deta**li**s".

I need to fix this, but I can't find where/which file it is in. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Generally,product list layout came from list.phtml file.

file location:app/design/frontend/default/my_theme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

(or)

Please enable the path hints via admin panel.It's show all block paths.

How do I turn on template path hints?

To turn on template path hints in Magento:

- log into the magento back-end admin
- Go to System -> Configuration in the main menu
- Go to Developer on the bottom left under ADVANCED
- Switch to the store view on the top left to your current website or
  store view.
- Under the Debug tab of the same Developer config page you will see a
  new option appear that will allow you to turn on/off template path
  hints.
- Remember to clear your cache.

Comment: Ok, thats helped a bit. it leads to;frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml. in there i find class="detail_button" but not the button label. where might that be?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I believe that the templates associated with products would be located in the

```
app/design/frontend/default/your_theme/template/catalog/product/
```

However, I am unsure of your site template files etc, especially if you are doing things yourself.

To make your life easier, I would suggest installing a program called Agent Ransack which I have found to be invaluable when searching for a needle in a haystack.